# How to customize the Delete button shown when swipe a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, customization, swipe

I have a table view and enabled the swipe to delete feature by providing an empty implementation of `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` of the table view controller.
I can see a red 'Delete' button when I swipe left the table cells.
But the button's label is 'Delete' despite that the system locale is not English.
I have too problems.
1. I want the Delete button to be localized according to the locale.
2. I want to add some other button, like that in the Podcast app of Apple.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is too much solutions... you should to search before posting new question. check this link:

[iOS Programming 101: How To Create Swipeable Table View Cell to Display More Options](http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/)

or use ready-made solutions like this:

https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

i can't post much links without 10 reputation, so try to google "custom delete button uitableviewcell"

Comment: I tried SWTableViewCell and it works fine.
But the original segue triggered by the table view cell when the cell is tapped does not work now. The cells now get selected when tapped but not trigger a segue. Could you give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: i cant test right now, but u can try to play with two flags in Attributes inspector: "delays content touches" and "cancellable content touches"