# UITableView customize delete button function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

As default behavior, once you want to delete any single cell of table view, you will tap on delete button at left of cel, the delete confirmation button will be shown at right of cell, and then continue tapping on this button, this row will be deleted. For this behavior, you need to have 2 steps to delete a row. Is there any way can only tap on delete button(at the left of cell) to delete the cell without tapping on the confirmation button?

Comment: Which left button? Take a screenshot please.

Comment: You can add a button on your table cell with delete icon image on it and then create customize method to delete table rows.

Comment: That is solution in my mind. But I'm not sure that will be the best way and looking forward to better solution.

Comment: Else there is swipe and delete features of table views by default.

Comment: CHECK THIS-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698054/how-to-customize-the-delete-button-shown-when-swipe-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean deleting the row only with swapping left? Ignoring the delete button?

You could use **UISwipeGestureRecognizer**, like this:

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didSwipe))
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
    }

    func didSwipe(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            let swipeLocation = swipe.locationInView(self.tableView)

            if let swipedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(swipeLocation) {

                if let swipedCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(swipedIndexPath) {

                    self.cellObjectsArray.remove(at: swipedIndexPath.row)
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [swipedIndexPath], with: .fade)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Questioner is asking that,  **Is there any way can only tap on left button to delete the cell without tapping on the confirmation button ?** not _deleting the row only with swapping left_

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I want to have the delete function that only need 1 tap on the delete button at left of cell, no need to continue to tap on the confirmation button at the right of cell. As default behavior, you must have 2 steps to delete a row.

Comment: If that's the case, I make Vahid's question my own: _Which left button? Take a screenshot please._

As far as I know default behaviour is swiping left and then confirming delete button.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the cell by implementing the following delegate methods, but this is a two step process,

1. Swipe the cell to find the delete confirmation button on right side
2. Click Delete (`commitEditingStyle` will be called)

If you want to do it in a single step/click, Add a custom button in `UITableViewCell` and in its selector get the `indexpath` of `UITableViewCell` and **delete the object from datasource and reload table**, This is similar to the code implemented in `commitEditingStyle` method.

---

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Delete";
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Delete the object at `indexPath` from datasource
    //Update UI, by reloading section/entire table
}
```